# Can I have a screensaver use all monitors as one?

Tags: macos, display, screensaver

I can have screensavers show on all my monitors, but I would like one that would use all screens as if they were one big monitor (so the animation would flow from one to the other). 
e.g. something like the swordfish screensaver: 
[image]

Is that possible, are there any out there?